# Detecting Implicit Transition From Python Int To (Unlimited) Long

Tags: python-2.7, exception, integer, biginteger

The [Python2 Docs On Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) state that

> Plain integers (also just called integers) are implemented using long in C, which gives them at least 32 bits of precision (sys.maxint is always set to the maximum plain integer value for the current platform, the minimum value is -sys.maxint - 1). Long integers have unlimited precision

I have some code which does non-scientific math operations on integers, and am concerned about implicit conversions from the former type to the latter:

1. presumably, the latter types are much less efficient than the former
2. more importantly, a transition to the latter probably signifies (at least in my code) some bug

It's possible to place code after each and every math operation to check for the type, but this would make even the expression

```
 a * b + 2 * c * d
```

into a cluttered glob of unreadable code.

Is there any way to set some exception to be thrown in case some number becomes too large for a regular int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set an exception in the current versions of Python. The Python developers have tried to hide the differences between the `int` and `long` types over time. In Python 3, the only integer type is the unlimited precision type (although it is called `int`).

Very old versions of Python (prior to 2.2; circa 2001) did not automatically promote the `int` type to the `long` type. An exception was raised instead. Unfortunately, this caused more bugs. I remember needing to initialize integer constants with a trailing `L` to force unlimited precision calculations. See [PEP 237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own class which extends int and then override its dunder methods, right?